# What is the correct definition of the Bayes rule?

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

I am familiar with
$$P(\theta|D)=\frac{P(D|\theta) \, P(\theta)}{P(D)}=\frac{P(D|\theta) \, P(\theta)}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(D|\theta) \, P(\theta) d\theta},\quad\theta\in \Theta$$
where the integration is with respect to $\theta$. However when reading about the consistency of the estimater $\theta$, I found the following definition in multiple [sources](http://www2.stat.duke.edu/%7Est118/sta941/Asymp.pdf)

Consider a sequence of samples $D^n=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ modeled as
$$D^n\sim p_n(d^n|\theta), \theta\in\Theta;\theta\sim \Pi_n$$
and $\Pi_n(.|D^n)$ denoting the posterior distribution on $\Theta$ based on the $n$-th sample:
$$\Pi_n(\mathcal{B}|D^n)=\frac{\int_\mathcal{B}p_n(d^n|\theta) \, d\Pi_n(\theta)}{\int_\mathcal{\Theta}p_n(d^n|\theta) \, d\Pi_n(\theta)},\qquad\mathcal{B}\subset\Theta$$

where here the integration is with respect to the distribution of $\theta$. Are these two definitions equivalent?

Source: [http://www2.stat.duke.edu/~st118/sta941/Asymp.pdf](http://www2.stat.duke.edu/%7Est118/sta941/Asymp.pdf)

Comment: The first integration is also with respect to the distribution of $\theta:$ that's what the appearances of "$P(\theta)$" accomplish.

Comment: @whuber, Isn't $\int_\mathcal{B}p_n(d^n|\theta) \, d\Pi_n(\theta)=\int_\mathcal{B}p_n(d^n|\theta) \, \Pi^\prime_n(\theta) d\theta$ so we should have $P^\prime (\theta)$ instead of $P(\theta)$ in the integral.

Comment: @whuber, Are you saying that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(D|\theta) \, P(\theta) d\theta=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(D|\theta) \,  d P(\theta)$? I am not sure this is correct.

Comment: The notation is awful, but that's the intention.

Comment: @whuber, I found this same notation in multiple papers relating to posterior consistency.

Comment: That means little.  However, I strongly suspect no individual paper conflated "$P(\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta$" with "$\mathrm{d}P(\theta).$"  Even when authors are being telegraphic or sloppy they rarely confuse a probability function with its density.

Comment: @whuber, If you see page 4 in https://web.stat.tamu.edu/~debdeep/Intro-cons-Bayes.pdf    the same method is used.

Comment: @whuber, here too https://pure.uva.nl/ws/files/44376469/Criteria_for_posterior_consistency_and_convergence_at_a_rate.pdf

Comment: I don't see any example of what you're writing about.

Comment: @whuber, Equation (2.1) in https://pure.uva.nl/ws/files/44376469/Criteria_for_posterior_consistency_and_convergence_at_a_rate.pdf looks similar to the equation above where integration is with respect to $\Pi(P)$

Comment: It is not.  You *must* understand the symbols in context.  The "$P$" there is an *outcome* in probability space.

Comment: @whuber what about the equation in page 4 in https://web.stat.tamu.edu/~debdeep/Intro-cons-Bayes.pdf where integration is with respect to $\Pi(f)$.

Comment: @whuber, here integration is with respect to $\Pi(p)$ https://www.dianacai.com/blog/2021/02/14/schwartz-theorem-posterior-consistency/#:~:text=Roughly%2C%20posterior%20consistency%20means%20that,the%20true%20density%20p0.

Comment: @whuber, I am sorry if this is becoming too long for you, but I would be very grateful if you could explain this in an answer. Thank you.